# MVC, Sql connection, Azure, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have a Controller with a method that gets data from a database. The website works fine local, but when publishing it as Azure-website, and entering the method url in webbrowser I get the error:

***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)***

Why do I get this error ?

here is my method in controller:

```
public string GetUser(int id){

    User user = new User();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getDbString());

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;
            cmd.Connection = conn;


            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from dbo.[USER] WHERE UserID='" + id + "'";

    conn.Open();

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                user.username = (reader["Username"].ToString());
                user.password = (reader["Password"].ToString());
                UserList.Add(user);
            }

    conn.Close();
    return UserList;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the error occurs when **conn.Open();**

this is how I get the ConnectionString:

```
    private string getDbString()
    {
        if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
        {
        connString =
            rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"];
        } 
        return connString.ToString();

    }
```

And this is the connectionString in Web.config within connectionStrings tag:

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:xxx;Database = myDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx@xxx;Password=xxx"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong, I had to link the Azure webpage to the SQL database server... ^^

Comment: how did u link Azure webpage to the SQL database server ?

Comment: @Christer Can you please Share how you link azure webpage to the sql dabase server?